# Printing in javascript a raw PDF that i get in php

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, printing

So, i am stuck trying to print a pdf throught an iframe or window in javascript. I am calling an API throught php that returns a pdf as a response. After saving it in the db, I have a method in php that  creates and echos `header("Content-type: application/pdf");` the page that contains the pdf. I call that method in javascript. It seems that when i try to load the src in the Iframe, it is not actually loaded when I get prompt to print the Iframe or window. Is there anyway to wait for the src to be loaded before calling any print method.

HTML

```
<iframe id="iframe" name="iframe"style="display: hidden;"></iframe>
```

Javascript

```
                        $.post("<?= site_url("fedexs/createShipment/") ?>",data,function(rep){
                            try {
                                if ( rep.HighestSeverity == 'SUCCESS' ){
                                    var trackingNumber = rep.CompletedShipmentDetail.MasterTrackingId.TrackingNumber;
                                    
                                
                                    var ifrm = document.getElementById("iframe");
                                    console.log('finished loading');
                                    console.log('iframe window finished');
                                    ifrm.setAttribute("src", "link that calls content Header" + trackingNumber);
                                    $("iframe").attr("src","link that calls content Header" + trackingNumber);
                                    console.log('iframe src created');
                                    document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow.print();
                            
                                
                            } catch (e){
                                console.log( [e,rep] );
                            }
                        });
```

PHP

```
//Get the correct info throught the db then
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
echo base64_decode($row->pdf_label);
```